# Need to create a table which summarizes the mean and sd of several variables for about 40 subsets

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm learning **R** and I have a dataset with about 6,000 daily records of three weather variables. I'm interested in knowing the mean and sd for each variable for each season in each year. I've found a bunch of different ways to break the data down into subsets. However, I can't figure out how calculate these without typing in `mean(s1997$tmax)` & `sd(s1997$tmax)` for each one. I would like to produce something that looks like this:

```
Season    mean.TMAX   sd.TMAX   mean.TMIN   sd.TMIN
s1997
f1997
w1997
s1998
```

I'm not even sure that **R** can do this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested in the absence of data:

```
aggregate( s1997[, c("TMAX", "TMIN") ], 
           s1997["Season"], 
           function(x) c(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x) ) )
```

The test:

```
aggregate(data.frame(state.x77), list(Region = state.region), 
                                 function(x) c( mean= mean(x), sd=sd(x) ) )
         Region Population.mean Population.sd Income.mean Income.sd
1     Northeast        5495.111      6079.565   4570.2222  559.0771
2         South        4208.125      2779.508   4011.9375  605.4505
3 North Central        4803.000      3702.828   4611.0833  283.0825
4          West        2915.308      5578.607   4702.6154  663.9004
  Illiteracy.mean Illiteracy.sd Life.Exp.mean Life.Exp.sd Murder.mean
1       1.0000000     0.2783882    71.2644444   0.7438769    4.722222
2       1.7375000     0.5524189    69.7062500   1.0221994   10.581250
3       0.7000000     0.1414214    71.7666667   1.0367285    5.275000
4       1.0230769     0.6084870    71.2346154   1.3519715    7.215385
  Murder.sd HS.Grad.mean HS.Grad.sd Frost.mean  Frost.sd Area.mean
1  2.670570    53.966667   3.928104  132.77778  30.89408  18141.00
2  2.627602    44.343750   5.741773   64.62500  31.30682  54605.12
3  3.569345    54.516667   3.622865  138.83333  23.89307  62652.00
4  2.675770    62.000000   3.500000  102.15385  68.87652 134463.00
    Area.sd
1  18075.69
2  57965.27
3  14967.02
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't break your data into subsets, then you can use the `data.table` library -

```
library(data.table)
RawData <- data.table(
Season = c("s1997","s1997","s1997","s1997","f1997","f1997","f1997","f1997"),
TMAX = rnorm(40,8),
TMIN = rnorm(10,8)
)
MeanData <- RawData[,
   list(
      TMAXmean = mean(TMAX),
      TMINmean = mean(TMIN)
   ),
   by = "Season"
]
```

The `RawData` looks like this -

```
> RawData
   Season     TMAX      TMIN
1:  s1997 40.87113 10.474463
2:  s1997 40.16536  9.437184
3:  s1997 41.39432  9.562281
4:  s1997 40.08575 10.357866
5:  f1997 39.14282  8.880483
6:  f1997 39.47253 10.674257
7:  f1997 38.30043 10.493501
8:  f1997 38.16162 10.758552
```

And the output like this -

```
> MeanData
   Season TMAXmean  TMINmean
1:  s1997 40.62914  9.957948
2:  f1997 38.76935 10.201699
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. However, I think I left out some important info, sorry. The reason I had been trying to divide it into subsets is because the data isn't already divided into seasons. Right now TMAX, TMIN and PRCP are all associated with a single date like 19990701, which would be the first day of s1999. I don't just want to replace the dates because though summer and winter are 2-3 months and continuous, fall's calculations include the winter of that year (has to do with the organism I'm working with).

Comment: I've named variables that refer to the correct ranges but I can't find a way to group them all together under a heading like season. I just used s1997<-will.data[will.data$DATE>=19970701 & will.data$DATE<=19970831,]. Though I also tried making them subsets and replacing the dates using ifelse, though that wouldn't allow me to just put in the name of the season b/c the object wasn't defined. Thanks for the help and I'm sorry for leaving that out.

Comment: Why don't you store each subset as the element of a list and use `lapply` over that whole list?